# Giving a vector of pixels as input to tensorflow

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I am using Tensorflow for a image classification problem in C++.

I created the graph and tried using the example code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc).

When I give an image (.jpeg) as the input to the main function (for `string image` in the main function) it works fine. But I have the pixel values of an image (luminance values only) in a 2d vector `std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec2d`. How can I give this vector as input for making a prediction?

I got a tensor created as follows, but I cannot figure out how to fit that to the existing code.

```
tensorflow::Tensor input(tensorflow::DT_FLOAT, 
tensorflow::TensorShape({32, 32}));
auto input_map = input.tensor<float, 2>();


for (int b = 0; b < 32; b++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < 32; c++) {
      input_map(b, c) = (vec2d)[b][c];
    }
}
```

Or is there an inbuilt way to pass pixel values in tensorflow?

I do not want to create an image with the pixel values and re-read it. I already did and it works but it takes time for file read/write operations and time is very crucial in my system.